# Question about the syntax after a FROM or a PIVOT. Are the ALIASes a "must"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax

I am new to MS SQL SERVER. I have some functional code that I got from some online sources. It does work.
The main problem is that there are random bits that do not match the notation I checked on the MSSS Help feature which I'll paste below with the other code to make the comparison easier.

I tried removing those bits of code, but it gave me errors and I get that the syntax in the do cumentation supports that.

The *weird* parts are marked with ** double asterisks inside the code blocks. It is "ratingfilter" where we should have the FROM's AS alias part for the first case. And for the second case, it is the same thing as the first one plus a similar anomaly ("a") for the PIVOT's clause ALIAS.

I developed a theory that the ALIASes mentioned in the documentation are a "must" but the syntax for them is actually flexible. **I think that because typing the AS was not required** and even a simple letter "a" worked on the second example.

Documentation

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,  
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    ...  
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>  
FROM  
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)   
    AS <alias for the source query>  
PIVOT  
(  
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)  
FOR   
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]   
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])  
) AS <alias for the pivot table>  
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

Anomaly notation for FROM

```
WITH cte_result AS(
SELECT 
m.movieid ,m.title ,ROUND(r.rating,0) AS [rating], 
CAST(ROUND(r.rating,0) AS VARCHAR(5))+'_rating' AS [Star]
FROM [movielens].[dbo].[rating] r 
JOIN [movielens].[dbo].[movie] m ON m.movieid=r.movieid )

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    movieid AS [MovieId],
    title AS [Movie Name],
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) AS [noofuser],
    CAST(SUM(Rating) AS FLOAT) AS [sumofrating],
    CAST(AVG(Rating) AS FLOAT) AS [avgofrating],
CASE WHEN star IS NULL THEN 't_rating' ELSE star END [RatingGrade]
FROM cte_result WHERE MovieId <= 2 GROUP BY ROLLUP(movieid,title,star) )**ratingfilter**
WHERE [Movie Name] IS NOT NULL ;
```

Anomaly notation for PIVOT

```
SELECT 
[MovieId],
[Movie Name],
[1_rating],
[2_rating],
[3_rating],
[4_rating],
[5_rating],
[t_rating] FROM
(SELECT 
    movieid AS [MovieId] ,
    title AS [Movie Name],
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) AS [noofuser],
    CASE WHEN star IS NULL THEN 't_rating' ELSE star END [RatingGrade]
FROM cte_result GROUP BY ROLLUP(movieid,title,star))**ratingfilter**
PIVOT (SUM([noofuser]) FOR [RatingGrade]
IN ([1_rating],[2_rating],[3_rating],[4_rating],[5_rating],[t_rating]))**a** 
WHERE [Movie Name] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY  movieid ;
```

The kind of error it gives when I remove these mysterious parts is simple and I understand it, but in case it helps I'll provide them:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.`
```

I'd appreciate if anyone could give some ideas as to how/why this code works, as the correct syntax should be "AS [alias for the column]".

Comment: The `AS` for declaring the alias is optional. Yes alias's are must haves in spots like that, because otherwise you have no way to reference the fields they product.

Comment: Oh, I did not had my mindset ready foro something as simple as that. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Ben Could you submit that as an answer? That cleared my doubts on the syntax and it would be nice to make you take the credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'AS' for declaring the alias is optional. Yes alias's are must haves in spots like that, because otherwise you have no way to reference the fields they produce.